# Stop Apache serving filetypes

Tags: apache, htaccess, webserver, httpd.conf

Preferably using `.htaccess` files, though `.conf` files are an option, is there any way to stop Apache serving certain filetypes?

For example, `.db` shouldn't be served for obvious reason (privacy and whatnot, etc.), so could I make them show as a `404` but still have them available for my CGI scripts?

Putting these sensitive files in a directory other than `/public_HTML/` is also an option, though I like having them in the same directory as the scripts for ease of use.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have said that placing these sensitive files above the document root would be preferable. And perhaps easier to manage if they are all contained in a particular directory, however...

Using .htaccess to prevent access to all `.db` and `.exe` files and return a 403 - Forbidden.

```
<Files ~ "\.(db|exe)$">
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Unless you have a specific requirement, I would have thought a 403 would be better than a 404 in this instance, and this would seem more natural for Apache. To return a 404 here would require additional code.